# Multiple image upload in Backpack/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-backpack

I am making a photography website, and I have categories there. For example: "Wedding", "Streets" and etc. However, I want to add many images to particular category at once, and I have another table for this called "**images**" table. It has 2 columns: `name` and `category_id` . In [Backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/introduction) it has "upload multiple field", however it uploads as an array inside one column. Which ways do you suggest to upload multiple photos to '**images**' table and manipulate them easily? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can rewrite store and update logic in your CrudController (`store` and `update` methods).

Comment: If you are uploaded quite a few at once I'd recommend created a job and dispatching them by looping through all of the images that you are uploading at once.